# JS/jQuery Change CSS with if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background image of a div using an if/else statement after a user clicks a part of the page. With the code below, the div will collapse as intended, however the accompanying background image does not change.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".titles-us").click(function() {
        $(".map-us").toggle();
        $(".map-tri").hide();
        $(".map-can").hide();
        $(".map-eur").hide();
        if ($(".us-icon").css('background-image') === 'url("public/images/collapse-lg.png")') {
            $(".us-icon").css({
                'background-image' : 'url("public/images/expand-lg.png")'
            });
        }
        else {} 
    });
});
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Sorry the background image is not changing from the if/else statement

Comment: Please update your post with question specified.

Comment: $(".us-icon").css('background-image') will give you url("http : // SITE/public/images/collapse-lg.png") so it will go to the else

Answer (score 0):

You can always addClass() with jQuery. Add a class when the user clicks the element. And give that class a background attribute different from the background of the element without that class.

```
if ($(".us-icon").hasClass('collapsed') == false) {
        $(".us-icon").addClass('collapsed');
} 
// If you want to remove the background on second click:
else {
        $(".us-icon").removeClass('collapsed');
}
```

In your css, you can add this:

```
.collapsed {
    background-image: url("public/images/expand-lg.png")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a setup like this adding/referring to a class

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".titles-us").click(function() {
  $(".map-us").toggle();
  $(".map-tri").hide();
  $(".map-can").hide();
  $(".map-eur").hide();
  if ($(".us-icon").hasClass('img-collapse'){
    $(".us-icon").removeClass('img-collapse').addClass('img-expand');
  }
  else{
    $(".us-icon").removeClass('img-expand').addClass('img-collapse');
  } 
  });
});
```

and in your CSS:

```
.img-collapse{
background-image : url("public/images/collapse-lg.png");
}

.img-expand{
background-image : url("public/images/expand-lg.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why your original code isn't sufficing, but here's a working example you can use to compare:

```
$(".us-icon").on('click', function() {
    var myEl = $(this);
    var bgimg = myEl.css('background-image');
    if( bgimg === "url(http://placehold.it/200x200)" ) {
        myEl.css({ 'background-image' : 'url(http://placehold.it/100x100)' });
    } else {
        myEl.css({ 'background-image' : 'url(http://placehold.it/200x200)' });
    }
});
```

( [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9E2Br/) )